# Pass image from JSF bean to Applet

Tags: java, jsf, applet

I meant to post this as a comment at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552202/how-to-pass-image-from-applet-to-jsf-backing-bean) but I don't have enough rep and I saw no other way but to ask a new question (although it seems a bit redundant).

Anyway, I tried the solution **skuntsel** wrote, but backwards: I encoded the image and sent it from the bean to a javascript method (I'm using icefaces so I called it like this `JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), functionCall)`).  I get the  encoded string in the Applet just fine, but when I try to decode it, nothing happens, the code following it is unreachable.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's the code I'm using.

**In the bean: (method triggered by a button click)**

```
BufferedImage originalImage = acquireImage();
byte[] imageInByte = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
      ImageIO.write( originalImage, "png", baos );
      baos.flush();
      imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
      baos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

String imageAsString = Base64.encodeBase64String(imageInByte);
JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), functionCall);
```

**In Javascript:**

```
function getEncodedImage(image){
      var applet = document.getElementById("Applet");
      applet.decodeImage(image);
}
```

**In the applet:**

```
public void decodeImage(String image) {
    System.out.println(image); //works
    byte[] imageByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(image);
    System.out.println("something"); //doesn't print anything   
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray);

    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("D:/image.png"));
            is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
           }

}
```

Comment: You problem is unclear. Broaden the context and add the code to the question. And, yes, simply revert the logics in the answer you referred to.

Answer (score 0):

The only suspicious part is `JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), functionCall);`: I don't see any `functionCall` definition. Despite, replace `functionCall` by `"getEncodedImage(" + image + ")"` and it should work.

I haven't worked with ICEfaces to say anything new about how `JavascriptContext#addJavascriptCall()` works, but there is a standard JSF solution: have a hidden input that contains the encoded string set in an action method and add a JS callback via AJAX.

Namely, the bean part:

```
private String imageAsString;//getter + setter
public void encodeImage() {
    ...
    this.imageAsString = Base64.encodeBase64String(imageInByte);
}
```

And the view:

```
<script>
    function update(data){
        if(data.status == "success") {
            var applet = document.getElementById("Applet");
            var image = document.getElementById("form:image").value;
            applet.decodeImage(image);
        }
    }
</script>
...
<h:form id="form">
    ...
    <h:inputHidden id="image" value="#{bean.imageAsString}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.encodeImage}">
        <f:ajax render="image" onevent="update" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Comment: I've tried with the hidden input and the result was the same, this is why I chose `addJavascriptCall()`. functionCall is the result of a function that builds the javascript call, the outcome will be something like `getEncodedImage(imageAsString);` (where imageAsString is the actual encoded image). Anyway, I was told to use a different approach, but I'm still curious as to why this doesn't work....